# Create new column with conditional operations on existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm extracting data within certain ranges and coming up with new columns that represent 1 when the values in a column fall within that range and 0 when they don't.

I tried using boolean conditions with no luck.

```py
data["normal"]=np.where((data["sysBP"]<80) & (data["diaBP"]<120),1,0)

data["prehyper"]=np.where(((data["sysBP"]<90) & (data["sysBP"]>=80)) & 
                          ((data["diaBP"]<140) & (data["diaBP"]>=120)),1,0)
```

I expect the new column show 1 for that data that lies within the range and 0 for those that don't. I got a column with all 0s with my above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the astype(int) to convert True to 1 and False to 0:

```
data["normal"] = ((data["sysBP"]<80) & (data["diaBP"]<120)).astype(int)

data["prehyper"] = ((data["sysBP"]<90) & (data["sysBP"]>=80) & (data["diaBP"]<140) & (data["diaBP"]>=120)).astype(int)
```

Comment: I converted the float type columns to int before running this line of code. I also tried the your suggestion but it still keeps giving an all 0 column.

Comment: @Kurapatiteju is there a typo (that it should read >80) in `(data["sysBP"]<80) & (data["diaBP"]<120)` ?

Comment: No, there isn't. I pasted the line of code you commented and gives this error- "'tuple' object has no attribute 'astype'". I require and for both the statements

Comment: @Kurapatiteju "tuple" ? `((data["sysBP"]<80) & (data["diaBP"]<120))` should be a Series not a tuple, is there a rogue comma in your code?

Comment: @Kurapatiteju pretty sure this should read `((data["sysBP"]>80) & (data["diaBP"]<120)).astype(int)`, note the >80 rather than <80.

Comment: @Kurapatiteju please accept this answer if it helped! Thanks https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/184179